# networkActivityIndicatorVisible not Working (Synchronized Request)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiactivityindicatorview

```
-(IBAction) webRequest;
{
    response = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]
                                initWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString:kResourcesURL]
                                cachePolicy: NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
                                timeoutInterval: 10];
    [theRequest setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"accept"];
    [theRequest setValue:strToken forHTTPHeaderField:@"token"];

    //show network activity indicator
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;

    response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest returningResponse:&urlresponse error:&nserror];
    NSString *strResponse = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    SBJsonParser *sbjasonparser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
    arrResponse = [sbjasonparser objectWithString:strResponse error:nil];

    //hide network activity indicator
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
}
```

Is there something wrong with my code? or Synchronized request makes any difference???
Any Suggestion ?? Or Should i use AcivityIndicator view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that the network activity indicator requires a layout of some views, that is, when you make it (in)visible it sends `[self setNeedsLayout]` at some point. This method does not cause the layout immediately, it just marks the view as needing layout with the actual layout happening *at the end of the run loop*. The problem in your case is that you block the main thread with a synchronous request so that the end of the run loop occurs *after* you make the indicator invisible again.

There is the only way to avoid blocking the main thread: make it asynchronous from the main thread's point of view. You can

- use asynchronous NSURLConnection API;
- use synchronous NSURLConnection API on a background thread;
- use synchronous NSURLConnection API with NSOperationQueue.

The idea is to show the network activity indicator, start a network request, let the main thread's run loop spin, and hide the indicator when the request is complete.

Comment: Quite right. You must not perform synchronous network requests (or any other such time consuming work) on the main thread. Your app will be unresponsive until that task completes. Not only is this a bad user experience but the OS will terminate your app when it is unresponsive for too long. As soon as you try the synchronous approach shown in this question under real world network conditions you app will look like it locked up and crashed.

Comment: @Jonah: what if the nextview's layout is totally dependent on the response to the current request???

Comment: @codeCube: You could use `NSURLConnectionDelegate` methods. If you choose a background thread or `NSOperationQueue` route, use `-performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:` to call your view configuration code. If you can afford an iOS 5 only code, put the view configuration into the completion block of `+sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:`.

Comment: @Costique: NSOperationQueue is not for iOS, i guess. I tried finding it, got for only Mac.

Comment: @codeCube: `NSOperationQueue` is "available in iOS 2.0 and later", according to both the docs and the header files. Certain methods were added in iOS 4.0, though.